# Using External HDD just like a normal Internal one

Tags: external-hard-drive

Is it okay if I use an external HDD like a normal Internal HDD, for example powered-on and connected most of time I'm using my computer?

I'm currently working on a small game, and I'm constantly moving my Project folder to my laptop when I'm developing it at my school or a friend's place.

So if going for an External one, I would place my Main project folder in it, then I would be developing/editing my game's folder directly from the external HDD (that would be constantly reading/writing for some long durations). Is this okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely fine and as long as you have good power and data connections should cause no problems at all.

Answer (score 1):

You ought to make sure of two things. First, that speed is not a prioity (external drives are usually slower, 5400rpm since the USB connection is the limiter). Second, will it overheat?

I did exactly what you want to do with my Caviar green WD 1TB, and when I opened the case, it was burning hot. Usually these drivers are not made to be on all the time. So I lost on performance, but in the end it worked fine. It is actually my internal backup drive now.

So if you really need, bottom line is yes, you can do it. But buying a decent internal HDD, specially for you that will work with it, should be your best option.

Answer (score 1):

It might be simpler to install Dropbox (https://www.dropbox.com/ ) on the machines you'll be developing on.

This works (for free) *only* if:

you have network access whereever you're developing (school or your friend's place)

you have enough local storage on your machines for these files (because Dropbox really only syncs your files between its servers and your machines)

your project files fit within 2GB (or whatever is free after any other use you have for Dropbox).  But it should be easy to configure your Main project folder to reside in Dropbox, and any output or static files larger than 2GB to live in the computer's local filesystem.

(Note:  I'm not connected with Dropbox other than being a satisfied user.  Having said that, we can both pick up an extra quarter-gig of space if you use my referral code:  http://db.tt/nBgcOHs )

Comment: just made an account through your referral :)

Comment: I prefer this option myself. If this is not possible, try project hosting sites like Github or Bitbucket. The same constraints apply (having network access, etc.).